# Install Safe CLI, to withdraw money from bsc

Tags: safe-core

im not a programmer and i need CLI, who can help me? I create bsc wallet with the same wallet address as on etherium but i can't see funds and can't do any transfer

Comment: https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40812-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover